# How do I spread the news of my new chat room?

Tags: discussion, chat, self-promotion

What should you do if you make a new chat room, and you want people to know about it? Do you post something in the meta of that site, or do you just find similar chat rooms?

Answer (score 7):

Treat your chat room the same way you would treat any other thing you want to advertise -- a question (maybe on another network site), a blog post, a music download, or whatever.  Mention it *in places where that information would be welcome*, and in a non-disruptive way.

For example, if your chat room is for people to geek out on a new SF movie, you could mention it in the chat rooms on Movies & TV and Science Fiction & Fantasy.  Wait for a lull in the conversation, introduce yourself, disclose that it's yours, invite people, and don't pester after that.  You'll probably be better received if you hang out in the room you're visiting and participate in the discussion there first; drive-by advertisers, even if on-topic, always cause some raised eyebrows and the occasional flag.

Using meta posts to advertise a site/chat room/etc is generally frowned on.  If it's a resource specifically useful to the site you're posting on and that site has a "useful resources" meta post (some do), you could add it there.  Beyond that, using meta for promotional purposes is likely to generate negative feedback from the community.

While [how not to be a spammer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) in the Help Center is oriented toward Q&A rather than chat, I recommend reading it for general philosophy.